# drop nested column from panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a normalized dataframe that contains nested data.

```
    timestamp               temp    weather
0   08/01/2021 00:00:00     17.82   [{'id': 800, 'main': 'Clear', 'description':... 
1   08/01/2021 01:00:00     17.12   [{'id': 800, 'main': 'Clear', 'description':... 
2   08/01/2021 02:00:00     16.53   [{'id': 800, 'main': 'Clear', 'description':...
```

I have extracted the nested data into another dataframe using:

```
 df_history_small = pd.json_normalize(data_history['hourly'], record_path='weather',meta=['dt','temp', 'humidity'], errors='ignore')
```

like this I got:

```
id  main    description         icon    dt                     temp     humidity
0   800     Clear   clear sky   01n     08/01/2021 00:00:00     17.82   69
1   800     Clear   clear sky   01n     08/01/2021 01:00:00     17.12   72
2   800     Clear   clear sky   01n     08/01/2021 02:00:00     16.53   74
```

now I want to drop the columns 'main', description and icon but get an error:

```
df_history_small = df_history_small.drop([('main', 'description', 'icon')], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

How can I drop these columns.

merci A

Comment: Specify those columns as a list of the column names, not a list of a single tuple, as pandas interprets that as a MultiIndex with 3 labels.

Comment: Also, no need to add ```inplace=True``` at the end, as you are assigning back to a new DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `drop` and fix your syntax as suggested by @ALollz:

```
>>> df.drop(['main', 'description', 'icon'], axis='columns')
    id                   dt   temp  humidity
0  800  08/01/2021 00:00:00  17.82        69
1  800  08/01/2021 01:00:00  17.12        72
2  800  08/01/2021 02:00:00  16.53        74
```